# vb.net proper way to thread this application

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

My application is a web scraper (for the most part) that stores information in a database.  I have 2 classes so far:

1. clsSpyder - This essentially rolls-up the scraper processes
2. clsDB - This does any database processes

My test program looks over all the URLs, scrapes, pushes into the database.  It is pretty simple sequentially, but I would like to have say N number of threads running those processes (scrape and store).  My sequential code is this:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click


    'Grab List
    Dim tDS As New DataSet
    Dim tDB As New clsTermsDB
    Dim tSpyder As New clsAGDSpyder
    Dim sResult As New TermsRuns

    'Grab a list of all URLS
    tDS = tDB.GetTermsList(1)

    Try

        For Each Row As DataRow In tDS.Tables(0).Rows

            rtbList.AppendText(Row("url_toBeCollected") & vbCrLf)
            sResult = tSpyder.SpiderPage(Row("url_toBeCollected"))

            'If nothing is found, do not store
            If sResult.html <> "" And sResult.text <> "" Then
                tDB.InsertScrape(Now(), sResult.html, sResult.text, Row("url_uid"), 1)
            End If

        Next

        Exit Sub

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

With that in mind and noting that I am passing variables to the SpiderPage and InsertScrape methods.. How could I implement threading?  It's gotta be simple, but I feel like I have been googling and trying things for days without success :(

*** ADDED: SpiderPage method:

```
    Public Function SpiderPage(PageURL As String) As TermsRuns
    Dim webget As New HtmlWeb
    Dim node As HtmlNode
    Dim doc As New HtmlDocument
    Dim docNOHTML As HtmlDocument

    Dim uri As New Uri(PageURL)
    Dim wc As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(uri.AbsoluteUri), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim wcStream As Stream


    wc.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    wc.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 3

    'Set Headers
    wc.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; I; Intel Mac OS X 11_7_9; de-LI; rv:1.9b4) Gecko/2012010317 Firefox/10.0a4"
    wc.Headers.Add("REMOTE_ADDR", "66.83.101.5")
    wc.Headers.Add("HTTP_REFERER", "66.83.101.5")


    'Set HTMLAgility Kit Useragent Spoofing (not needed, I don't think)
    webget.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; I; Intel Mac OS X 11_7_9; de-LI; rv:1.9b4) Gecko/2012010317 Firefox/10.0a4"

    'Certification STuff
    wc.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    wc.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications

    'Create Cookie Jar
    Dim CookieJar As New CookieContainer
    wc.CookieContainer = CookieJar

    'Keep Alive Settings
    wc.KeepAlive = True
    wc.Timeout = &H7530

    'Read the web page
    Dim wr As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Try

        wcStream = wc.GetResponse.GetResponseStream

        doc.Load(wcStream)

        'Remove HTML from the document
        docNOHTML = RemoveUnWantedTags(doc)

        'Grab only the content inside the <body> tag
        node = docNOHTML.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body")

        'Output
        SpiderPage = New TermsRuns
        SpiderPage.html = node.InnerHtml
        SpiderPage.text = node.InnerText
        Return SpiderPage

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Something goes here when scraping returns an error
        SpiderPage = New TermsRuns
        SpiderPage.html = ""
        SpiderPage.text = ""

    End Try


End Function
```

*** Added InsertScrape:

```
Public Function InsertScrape(scrape_ts As DateTime, scrape_html As String, scrape_text As String, url_id As Integer, tas_id As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim myCommand As MySqlClient.MySqlCommand

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    'Create ds/dt for fill
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dtbl As New DataTable

    Try

        'Set Connection String
        myConn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString

        'Push Command to Client Object
        myCommand = New MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
        myCommand.Connection = myConn
        myCommand.CommandText = "spInsertScrape"
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scrape_ts", scrape_ts)
        myCommand.Parameters("@scrape_ts").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scrape_html", scrape_html)
        myCommand.Parameters("@scrape_html").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scrape_text", scrape_text)
        myCommand.Parameters("@scrape_text").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url_id", url_id)
        myCommand.Parameters("@url_id").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tas_id", tas_id)
        myCommand.Parameters("@tas_id").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

        'Open Connection
        myConn.Open()
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()


        'Close Connection
        myConn.Close()

        InsertScrape = True

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Put Message Here
        InsertScrape = False
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should show us the `InsertScrape` and `SpiderPage` methods too, so that we know what we're dealing with? What we currently see is code that don't seem to need multithreading.

Comment: What you will need for multithreading: Threads, Delegate methods, Invocation, checking `InvokeRequired`. --- Every call to a UI element should be invoked if `InvokeRequired` returns True.

Comment: Your code seems to be using WinForms which must use a Single Thread Apartment. If you use `Task`s and `Async` and `Await` you'll be able to yield control between tasks but any GUI changes will need to be synchronized to the main GUI thread.

Comment: @Jordell : Why would it need that? WinForm applications are automatically delared as `Multi Thread Apartment`.

Comment: I didn't put the other methods in there because they aren't very 'clean'.  Essentially I want threading because I have a bunch of URLs and I don't want it to take an hour to scrape them all.. I want it to take minutes.  I will sanitize and put those methods up there.

Comment: Well if those methods do UI calls and you don't show them to us, you're not going to be able to perform completely working multithreading.

Comment: @VisualVincent, unless this has changed you are wrong, WinForms are STA only. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Added the 2 methods.  There are no UI calls mainly because this will eventually be a service that runs in the background.  This is just a 'testing ground' to have it in WinForms.

Comment: use TAP https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx, don't use `Invoke`, `BeginInvoke` or `Thread.Start`. You will need to make safe cross-thread calls if using WinForms https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jordell : I don't have any references, no. But I _was_ pretty sure I've seen `<MTAThread()>` above most applications' main method that I've looked at, but I guess that isn't the case then... Also, just to point out to the OP: There's nothing wrong with `Invoke` and `Thread`s, it's just a bit oldschool (and since I use VS 2010 I don't have the new `Async`/`Await` methods :) ).

Comment: I will look at the Async / Await methods.  I am using VS2015, so shouldn't have a problem from that perspective.  Hopefully that will work based upon the code I have above?

Comment: With Await, won't it run async, but still not run the next process until that is completed - or am I reading it wrong? Sorry - I have no experience with Async.

Comment: @Jordall : You tell him to not use `Invoke`, then you refer him to an article using exactly that. ;)

Comment: @OP : `Await` is used when you want to wait for a task to complete, and it is to be called inside your method and not in it's declaration.

Comment: Example: `Await tDB.InsertScrape(...)`. If you'd call `Await` from the UI thread (if even possible) I suppose it'd block it until the task has finished.

Comment: ok. then if I am waiting for a task to complete I can see how that would help a GUI remain responsive while a task is happening, but how will that help the processes run more quickly?  Wouldn't it stay the same?  Sorry if I am not understanding.

Comment: If you wait for a task to finish on the UI thread, the UI _**will not**_ be responsive. --- Also, neither `Async` methods nor `Threads` will make this go faster, you'll just be able to run multiple scrapings at once without blocking the UI thread. Think of it like this: _If you were to solve a time-consuming problem, it won't go faster just because you go into another room._

Comment: If I ran the process in parallel with 4 threads on a quad-core processor - wouldn't that speed it up?  Maybe I am just not thinking this through properly?

Comment: That depends on how you are running it in parallel, and what you mean by _"on 4 threads"_.

Comment: I am probably assuming too much here... but if I ran 4 threads with 4 processes at the same time, wouldn't that be in parallel and wouldn't they run simultaneously because of the multiple cores?  Maybe I just don't know what I am talking about :)  If so - sorry.. that was what I had thought.

Comment: If you run four (you can run more if you want to) scrapings it will do four scrapings. If each has got it's own thread they will most likely run parallel. _HOWEVER_ the process won't go any faster other than that you may perform _more_ scrapings in _less time_. But the scrapings themselves won't go any faster.

Comment: A little note: 4 cores does not equal a maximum of 4 threads (your system already uses more than that at the moment). The thread count is not just dependent on the processor. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4828359/3740093

Comment: makes sense and that is similar to what I thought... so, if I have 400 scrapings and I run 4 threads, I should (in theory) get 4x the overall speed (don't care about the individual speed of the processes).  I just want to cut the time down overall.