# How does jmeter simulate more threads(Users) than the actual number of my threads in cpu?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I just started to use jmeter to stress test my web site. As you might know there is a section in thread group where you just type down with how many users you want to test your web site. It works fine, and I am happy to use jmeter. But what I don't understand is that my pc has 2 cores and as I guess (I may be wrong about this) intel CPUs has 2 threads for each core which makes 4 threads in total, and I want to test my website with more than 4 people obviously so how does jmeter simulates these http requests since my pc cannot run more than 4 processes? Are these users just connections? Thank you very much.

Comment: It's more an hardware question see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828296/how-many-threads-can-i-run-concurrently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single-processor systems implement multitasking/multithreading via [time slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Time_slice) therefore you can run as many processes/threads as fits into your RAM (+ [swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging))

The only way to find out how many threads (virtual users) you can actually simulate using JMeter is follows:;

1. Set up monitoring of baseline OS health metrics: CPU, RAM, Disk, Network, aforementioned swap. You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this
2. Make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
3. Start with one virtual user and gradually increase the load until your system starts running out of resources (i.e. CPU usage exceeds 90%) - this is how many users you can mimic **for this particular machine for this particular test**. In case of other (or updated test) or hardware change you will have to repeat the exercise.

If it is enough to conduct your load testing - that's great. If not - you will have to consider [Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

More information: [What’s the Max Number of Users You Can Test on JMeter?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter)