# Qt 5.15 Updating QLineEdit styleSheet triggers... stack overflow

Tags: c++, qt, stack-overflow, qlineedit

I created a QSuperLine class that inherits from QLineEdit. The idea is for the line to nicely change it's background - flash - when the text is changed either by a user or from within the QApplication.
I do have a separate thread (named updater) that emits a freshUpdate signal with 100 msec intervals.

In principle this works as expected. However, when I have to update a large number of lines in my app, I can see that they 'flash' one by one instead of behaving independently, and - when they do - at some point I am getting a stack overflow exception.

Could someone more experienced with Qt tell me what could be improved in the below code to avoid this problem?

Below is my qsuperline.**h** content, QLineEdits have been promoted to qSuperLines in the Qt Designer. I use 64-bit MSVC.

```
#ifndef QSUPERLINE_H
#define QSUPERLINE_H
#pragma once

#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QObject>
#include "updater.h"
#include <QThread>

extern void delay(int millisecondsWait);

class QSuperLine : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QThread * T1 = new QThread();
    updater * Up1 = new updater();
    bool isBusy;
    QString InitialContent;

explicit QSuperLine (QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QLineEdit(parent) {
    Up1->moveToThread(T1);
    InitialContent = "";
    isBusy = false;
    QObject::connect( T1, &QThread::started, Up1, &updater::workNow);
    QObject::connect( Up1, &updater::freshUpdate, this, &QSuperLine::resetLine);
    T1->start();

}

QSuperLine::~QSuperLine() {

}

public slots:
    int QSuperLine::resetLine(int a) {
        if (InitialContent != this->text() && isBusy == false) {
            isBusy = true;
            InitialContent = this->text();
            this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(20, 80, 180);border-style: solid;border-width: 2px;border-color: red;border-radius: 9px;color: cyan;");
            delay(50);
            this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(20, 80, 160);border-style: solid;border-width: 2px;border-color: red;border-radius: 9px;color: cyan;");
            delay(50);
            this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(20, 80, 140);border-style: solid;border-width: 2px;border-color: red;border-radius: 9px;color: cyan;");
            delay(50);
            this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(20, 80, 120);border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;border-color: red;border-radius: 9px;color: cyan;");
            delay(50);
            this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(20, 80, 100);border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;border-color: red;border-radius: 9px;color: cyan;");
            delay(50);
            this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(20, 80, 80);border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;border-color: red;border-radius: 9px;color: cyan;");
            delay(50);
            this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(20, 80, 40);border-style: solid;border-width: 0px;border-color: red;border-radius: 9px;color: cyan;");
            delay(50);
            this->setStyleSheet("");
            this->isBusy = false;

        }
        return 0;
    }

};

#endif // QSUPERLINE_H
```

Now, the debugger tells me that line 14 in the assembly code becomes problematic (just in case this is helpful...)

```
        Qt5Guid!__chkstk [d:\agent\_work\63\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\misc\amd64\chkstk.asm @ 67]:
0x7ff802413cc0                   sub     rsp,10h
0x7ff802413cc4  <+    4>         mov     qword ptr [rsp],r10
0x7ff802413cc8  <+    8>         mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],r11
0x7ff802413ccd  <+   13>         xor     r11,r11
0x7ff802413cd0  <+   16>         lea     r10,[rsp+18h]
0x7ff802413cd5  <+   21>         sub     r10,rax
0x7ff802413cd8  <+   24>         cmovb   r10,r11
0x7ff802413cdc  <+   28>         mov   r11,qword ptr gs:[10h]
0x7ff802413ce5  <+   37>         cmp     r10,r11
0x7ff802413ce8  <+   40>         bnd jae Qt5Guid!__chkstk+0x42 (00007ff8`02413d02)
0x7ff802413ceb  <+   43>         and     r10w,0F000h
0x7ff802413cf1  <+   49>         lea     r11,[r11-1000h]
0x7ff802413cf8  <+   56>         mov     byte ptr [r11],0   # <- stack overflow here.
```

The exact error is:
d:\agent_work\63\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\misc\amd64\chkstk.asm:109: error: Debugger encountered an exception: Exception at 0x7ff802413cf8, code: 0xc00000fd: stack_overflow, flags=0x0 (first chance).

Comment: I am not sure if putting, as you have said 'a lot of SuperLines' each into different thread is a good solution, that's probably the reason it is not working independently. There is only 2*core_number threads on your processor, so if you have more threads, it will work but not completely concurrent(processor will break it's working time for different threads) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828296/how-many-threads-can-i-run-concurrently . Try to use less threads, if you want delay - delay only one thread and just signal the time that passed to all lines. But I suggest using QTimer.

Comment: Thanks, indeed - the number of QThreads attempting to run concurrently was a problem. I've fixed the issue by re-writing the code from scratch, using just one thread and one delay to iterate through a list of pointers to lines that had their content changed. It works like a charm. The code above is fundamentally wrong - unless run on a cluster, it will fail.